# jQuery reloading Date Picker not working on Chrome but it works on Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery, datepicker

I am implementing a jquery datepicker. when I am reloading the datepicker working fine on fireFox but I can not get it work on chrome.

```
        $('#startDate').datepicker("change", {
            beforeShowDay: function(date){

                return disableRangeOfDays(date, datesWithMyList);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you post some code? JQuery datepicker absolutely works in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In chrome timezone for the date is differrent when comapred to firefox 
thats causing datepicker to never enable listed dates.
Instead of creating object 
Date=new Date(myDate);

I am parsing the date:

```
function disableRangeOfDays(date, datesWithMyList){
for (var i = 0; i < datesWithMyList.length; i++) {
        var parsedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', datesWithMyList[i]);
        if (date.getDate() === parsedDate.getDate() && date.getMonth() === parsedDate.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() === parsedDate.getFullYear()) {
            return [true];
        }
    }

return [false];
```

}